# VB 2010 Element to Variable

Tags: visual-studio-2010, variables, data-structures

If you have built a structure in VB 2010 for a `HousePet` and you want to access the structure element called `Coat`, what would be the line of code required to move the element into the variable `Coat`?

```
Structure HousePet
   Public _Breed as String
   Public _PetCoat as String
   Public _Cost as Double
End Structure

   Sub Main()
        Dim HoundDog As HousePet
        Dim Coat as String
        **Insert Code Here**
   End Sub
```

Comment: Just on a side note, you are using wrong naming conventions for your variables. The norm is to prefix local variables with  an underscore (e.g. _SomeLocalVariable), while the Public variables should be declared without underscore and in Pascal casing.
So, the better way to name your structure variables would have been `Breed`, `PetCoat` and `Cost`. This doesn't harm your program though.

Answer (score 2):

First you need a variable of the Struct's type:

```
Private MyPet As HousePet
```

Then you can access it like this:

```
Coat = MyPet._PetCoat
```

Comment: @SiddharthRout Well, by sheer chance I'll beat you *once* in a while... :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
'Public _Cost as Double
'A Typo?
'Did you mean Public _Coat as Double

Sub Main()
    Dim HoundDog As HousePet
    Dim Coat As String

    Dim x As HousePet

    Coat = x._Cost 'Or is it a typo? x._Coat?
End Sub
```